# Как сделать, чтобы пользователь не админ мог назначать роли другим пользователям на Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Имеется сайт на Wordpress + WooCommerce. Вукоммерсом создается роль "менеджер магазина". Я хочу, чтобы пользователь с этой ролью мог назначить кастомные роли другим пользователям, находящимся в группе "клиент". Допустим я менеджер магазина, у меня есть обычный клиент, я хочу перенести его в "вип-килент" и дать ему другие цены с помощью плагина Product Prices by User Roles for WooCommerce... Я пробовал плагин User Role Editor, создал с помощью него новые роли, но клиентам эти роли присваивать может только Админ, а мне необходимо чтобы этим мог управлять менеджер магазина.

Comment: Ну вот с пом URE и настроить права менеджеру. Только засада в том, что он и админа может сделать, а это дыра.

Comment: в URE ставил даже все галочки, открывается полностью админка, но в пользователях в меню я могу дать роль только "клиент", ни кастомные, ни родные вордпрессовские не появляются.

Comment: Всё можно, см ответ. А по поводу "сделать админа" я был не прав - не может.

Answer (score 0):

> Я пробовал плагин User Role Editor, создал с помощью него новые роли,
> но клиентам эти роли присваивать может только Админ, а мне необходимо
> чтобы этим мог управлять менеджер магазина.

В User Role Editor достаточно поставить нужные права менеджерам

[image]

и появится возможность менять роль

[image]

Comment: да я ставил галочки напротив этих прав.. Появляется выбор роли, но в выпадающем списке отображется только "клиент", никаких других ролей для выбора нет.

Comment: в общем проблема в родном shop_manager... если клонировать админа, например через плагин member, все сразу работает.

Comment: Нет там никаких проблем. Этого "менеджера" я вообще перевёл из подписчиков и добавил ему возможность. Сравнивай др. возможности. Их перечень есть в профиле юзера.